# Tcp client in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I've created a simple server in raspberry pi 3 running Windows 10 IOT Core with uwp(Universal Windows Platform) with this class>

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
namespace UWP_Server
{
    public class StreamSocketManager
    {
        private StreamSocket ConnectionSocket;

        public static bool IsServer { get; set; }

        private string ServerPort = "8590";


        public void Open()
        {
            StreamSocketListener DataListener = new StreamSocketListener();
            DataListener.ConnectionReceived += ConnectionReceived;
            DataListener.BindServiceNameAsync(ServerPort).AsTask().Wait();
        }



        private async void ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            DataReader reader;
            StringBuilder sb;
            string receivedData = null;

            using (reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream))
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

                await reader.LoadAsync(256);

                while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
                    await reader.LoadAsync(256);
                }

                reader.DetachStream();
                receivedData = sb.ToString();
            }
            if (receivedData != null)
            {
                if (IsServer)
                {
                    MainPage.Current.Show("[SERVER] I've received " + receivedData + " from " +
                        args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName);
                    Debug.WriteLine("[SERVER] I've received " + receivedData + " from " +
                        args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName +
                        "\r\nIp: " + args.Socket.Information.LocalAddress + ":" +
                        args.Socket.Information.LocalPort +
                        "\r\nProtectionLevel: " + args.Socket.Information.ProtectionLevel +
                        "\r\nRemoteHostName: " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName +
                        "\r\nRemoteIP: " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteAddress + ":" +
                        args.Socket.Information.RemotePort +
                        "\r\nRemoteServiceName: " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteServiceName
                        );
                    Debug.WriteLine("");
                    Debug.WriteLine("");

                    SentResponse(args.Socket.Information.RemoteAddress, "Hello " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName);

                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("[CLIENT] I've received " + receivedData + " from "
                        + args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName +
                        "\r\nIp: " + args.Socket.Information.LocalAddress + ":" +
                        args.Socket.Information.LocalPort +
                        "\r\nProtectionLevel: " + args.Socket.Information.ProtectionLevel +
                        "\r\nRemoteHostName: " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteHostName +
                        "\r\nRemoteIP: " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteAddress + ":" +
                        args.Socket.Information.RemotePort +
                        "\r\nRemoteServiceName: " + args.Socket.Information.RemoteServiceName
                        );
                    Debug.WriteLine("");
                    Debug.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine("Received data was empty. Check if you sent data.");

        }


        public async void SentResponse(HostName address, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Connecting to " + address + Environment.NewLine);
                ConnectionSocket = new StreamSocket();

                await ConnectionSocket.ConnectAsync(address, ServerPort);

                DataWriter SentResponse_Writer = new DataWriter(ConnectionSocket.OutputStream);
                string content = message;
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

                SentResponse_Writer.WriteBytes(data);

                await SentResponse_Writer.StoreAsync();
                SentResponse_Writer.DetachStream();
                SentResponse_Writer.Dispose();
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection has been made and your message " + message + " has been sent." + Environment.NewLine);
                ConnectionSocket.Dispose();
                ConnectionSocket = new StreamSocket();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to connect ");
                ex.Exception("SentResponse");
                ConnectionSocket.Dispose();
                ConnectionSocket = null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

everything seems OK and It's worked in as Server.
I run this code in my Windows 10 mobile (as client) and I can received and send messages between my raspberry pi and windows mobile.

Now I want to send and receive message from my android phone.
I tested a-lot of codes but none of them worked to connect android to raspberry pi.
for android I used this nuget package >
https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

here is my code:

```
    void Send()
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Ramtin"), 8590);
        try
        {
            client.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Connected to server" + "\n");
                var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                WriteLine("Connected: " + client.Connected);
                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEy");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("send failed !");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Exception("Send");
        }
    }
```

"Ramtin" is my raspberry pi host name.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Note: I tried to create android as Server and other phones as clients and it's works fine(sending/receiving message). but I don't want android as a server!

Comment: What's the problem?  Do you get an error or exception?  Does it not compile?  Have you tried using the IP instead of hostname for the server?
  Please be more specific about the exact problem that you're having.

Comment: It doesn't work with host name, it throws an exception: An invalid IP address was specified.

Comment: IPAddress.Parse() expects an IP address, not a host name.  Which is exactly what the exception says.